# Proper way to include bootstrap 4 in a vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I use vue cli and want to use bootstrap 4. I installed the bootstrap npm package and imported the styles with `@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` in App.vue.

But I can't get the javascript for modal and dropdown working. I tried to include these files in the `index.html` but it doesn't helped:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I don't want to use vue-bootstrap.

Comment: If you don't want to include jQuery Bootstrap-vue is very good. Its a good idea to try and not use jQuery give you are using vue.js.. its sounds hard but you win component out there and building your own is much easier than jQuery. (I know you have indicated you dont want to use bootstrap vue but this advice has served me well..just trying to help)

Comment: You're right it is very easy to write this by myself so that's what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install jquery bootstrap popper.js --save
```

After that, import js and css in your main.js file. Like below. Hope it help

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
global.jQuery = jQuery
global .$ = jQuery
```